# Display a metric with a slow increment

Tags: grafana

I have my own counter type metric. It changes quite rarely: +1, +2 values per hour. I am trying to plot this metric on grafana so that the moment of change is displayed as a peak. I tried `rate(my_metric[1m])`, `irate(my_metric[1m])`, `increase(my_metric[1m])`, but the value is always 0 on the graph, although if output only `my_metric`, the values will grow.

How do I build a query so that the metric changes are visible?

Comment: What isa time range on you dashboard when you experience this? It might be that you "peak" is simply skiped due to resolution. I'd recommend using `$__rate_interval` instead of `1m` in your query (specifically one using increase).

Answer (score 0):

May try to change time window from 1m to 1h, like below:

```
rate(my_metric[1h])
```

And another solution may try to check some [grafana setting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/use-dashboards/)

Hope it may help